# Trying to create one line for database search result

Tags: javascript

I tried the following to get this effect:

- If there is no row, show ❌
- If there is a row but no reason, show ✅ No reason available
- If there is a row and a reason, show ✅ and the reason

```js
const query1 = await db.all(SQL`SELECT * FROM list WHERE name = ${user}`);
const result = query1 ? typeof query1 === 'object' && typeof query1.reason === 'string' ? `✅\n${query1.reason}` : '✅\nNo reason available' : '❌';
```

The output of query1 is:

```
[ { id: 2542, name: 'Mesa', reason: 'test' } ]
```

However I always get: ✅ No reason available, what do I have to change to make it work?

Comment: `query1` is `array`.

Comment: I am not familair with checking in one line for arrays, could you help me out?

Comment: which reason should be shown? the first? all?

Comment: query1[0] is the first row (line) of the result. query1[0].id should give you the id of the first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for `query1` and `query1.reason` in your if statement, yet this is misdirected. `query1` is an array that holds object items (persumably 1 object per for returned for the SQL db). So you should look for for `query1[0]` and `query1[0].reason` in order to establish it.

Notice that `typeof query1` still outputs an 'object' result since arrays are also Objects in javascript.

**edit**

Ok the annoying long line made me also miss out on another fault in your literal if statement. You are using two `:` operators. I am going to assume you mean this to be something along the lines of `if, else if, else` but that's not possible with 1 liners. it's only an `if, else` kind of operation.

You could nest another `if/else` statement after the `:` operator.

*so an example code:*

```
const q1 = [ { id: 2542, name: 'Mesa', reason: 'test' } ];
const q2 - [];
const q3 = [ { id: 2542, name: 'test'} ]

function getRes(q){
const res = typeof q[0] == 'object' && typeof q[0].reason == 'string' && q.length > 0 ? console.log("got result with reason string") : (q.length > 0) ?console.log("got result but not reason string") : console.log("got no result")
return res;
}

getRes(q1) // console output: got result with reason string
getRes(q2) // console output: got no result
getRes(q2) // console output: got result but not reason string
```

**HOWEVER**
This is extremely annoying code and would be super annoying to read and understand if someone has to maintain this later etc. I would definitely go with a regular `if(){},else if{}, else` option.

Comment: I can get the reason now, however when the output is [] it does not show the cross

Comment: can you post the if statement line? @Jay

Comment: if there's a reason, it should show the check mark + reason,
if there is no reason but there is a name it should show the checkmark without reason and if there is nothing it should show the cross

Comment: Oh ok i looked further - you are using two else options which is not allowed. let me  edit my answer quickly.

Comment: `return resolve(!!row ? typeof row === "object" && typeof row.reason === "string" ? '✅\n${row.reason}' : '✅\nNo reason' : "❌");` how come this worked fine? I wanted something like this but then for the array output

Comment: @Jay about the resolve thing - i am not sure how it works there. Probably something different about the way promises works. Maybe someone will add some info about that.

Answer (score 0):

since that query returns `array`, you need to check items in that array, not the array itself.

```js
const query = [ { id: 2542, name: 'Mesa', reason: 'test' },  { id: 2543, name: 'Mesa2', reason: undefined } ]

for(let data of query){
  const result = typeof data.reason === 'string' ? `✅\n${data.reason}` : '✅\nNo reason available';
  console.log(data)
  console.log(result)
}
```